# Django Annotate Getting full list of Users and add flag. Removing users that appear as duplicate

Tags: python, django

Been stuck on this for a good few hours now, I'm sure its something simple im missing.

I want to get full list of Users, but with 'participant' flag added if they are in Project.participants(m2m). That part works!

Model:

```
class Project(TimeStampedModel, Slugify):
    ...
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_participants')
    ...
```

```
User.objects.queryset.annotate(
    participant=Case(
        When(
            projects_project_participants__in=project_id,
            then=Value(project_id)
        ), 
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).order_by('id')
```

I can get the right results if I filter out the rest. But I want to keep full queryset with both true and false.

The issue is, if a User is part of 5 groups for instance, then I have both True and False records in data set. (i have 2 results as i have set distinct, but left with a true and false version from different projects).

Any ideas of best approach or a simple filter I am missing.

Result I get:

```
"data": [
        {
            "type": "User",
            "id": "1",
            "attributes": {
                "first_name": "Joe",
                "last_name": "Blogs",
                "is_active": true,
                "participant": 2   ------ (its in project)
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "User",
            "id": "1",
            "attributes": {
                "first_name": "Joe",
                "last_name": "Bloggs",
                "is_active": true,
                "participant": null.  ----- (this one should not be here)
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "User",
            "id": "2",
            "attributes": {
                "first_name": "Barry",
                "last_name": "Davis",
                "is_active": false,
                "participant": 2  ------ (its in project)
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "User",
            "id": "3",
            "attributes": {
                "first_name": "Betty",
                "last_name": "Davis",
                "is_active": false,
                "participant": null  ------ (not in project but i still want this result)
            }
        },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef
User.objects.annotate(
    in_project=Exists(
       Project.objects.filter(
           id=project_id,
           participants=OuterRef('pk'),
       )
    )
)
```